# Trying to return an itm from an Array or an Object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an issue... and i'm going crazy!

I get a object, in a variable (with Laravel, but it doesn't matter).

```
$searchImage = ListTypeImage::find($v->list_image_id);
return gettype($searchImage)
```

It returns *Object*.

The object:

```
{
    "id": 15,
    "titre": "Mariage 1",
    "list_type_id": 2,
    "image": "list\/sXoW4ZFzff0AuvSviIXFtHSrLy0SdTdq6shiBEpB.jpg",
    "created_at": "2021-06-02T12:58:41.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-06-02T12:58:41.000000Z"
}
```

When i write:

```
return $searchImage->image;
```

It returns *"list/sXoW4ZFzff0AuvSviIXFtHSrLy0SdTdq6shiBEpB.jpg"*

But when i write:

```
$image = $searchImage->image;
```

It returns an error: *Trying to get property 'image' of non-object*

I have the same issue with an array. If i convert my object into a array:

```
 return $searchImage['image'];
```

It returns *"list/sXoW4ZFzff0AuvSviIXFtHSrLy0SdTdq6shiBEpB.jpg"*

And if i wrote:

```
 $image = $searchImage['image'];
```

I have this error: *Trying to access array offset on value of type null*

Should I change my job?
Thanks a lot!

The entire code:

```
private function getImageOfSharedList($id)
    {
        $return = ListTypeImage::find($id);
        $return = json_decode($return);
        return $return->image;
    }


$image = $this->getImageOfSharedList($v->list_image_id);
```

Comment: _Should I change my job?_ Welcome to software development :D

Comment: Are you sure this is the only code snippet there is?

Comment: Yes it is. Only theses 2 lines.
$searchImage = ListTypeImage::find($v->list_image_id);
$image = $searchImage->image;

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible. See here https://onlinephp.io/c/b37c4 Notice the extra `,` removed at the end of `updated_at` in the json in the link.

Comment: Sorry, the final , is an error. I removed the last line (sensitive data), but there is not comma at the last line.

Comment: I am afraid I can't help you any further then.

Comment: No problem; thanks a lot for your time! I'm going to raise goats in the country.